# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> after CAS login

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

I Have Jboss on Windows and I'm using it from **Eclipse Luna**. I have deployed a `war` file that connects to another server through `https` for authentication, but after successful authentication, I get this error:

> PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I used `InstallCert` to get the certificate from the server (it has a chain of certificates and I got the "bigger" one, meaning the one from the authority that signed them all) and I imported into `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts` and I still get this error. Can someone help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a trusted site you should put **all** the root CA certificates in your truststore.

Here is the easiest:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -host [IP_ADDRESS_OF_THE_SSL_SERVER] -port [PORT_USUALLY_443] -prexit -showcerts > certs-chain.pem
```

Replace the part inside the square brakets (brakets included) with your actual running server

than
issue the following command:

```
echo "[PASSWORD]\n[PASSWORD]\nyes\n" | keytool -import -alias whatever -file certs-chain.pem -keystore trust.jks
```

at this point you can run your jvm with the following parameter

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStrore=trust.jks
```

Comment: How do I run with parameters? My war is a servlet deployed on jboss.

Comment: Here an example on how to use them https://asciinema.org/a/4o77770elr1coblu53okjl5pm    it ends with an error because I press ctrl-C but it worked trust me I'm an engineer :) .